# How to limit an array of similar hashes to those that have more than one of the same key:value pair (details inside)

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array like this

```
arr = [ { name: "Josh", grade: 90 }, {name: "Josh", grade: 70 }, 
{ name: "Kevin", grade: 100 }, { name: "Kevin", grade: 95 }, 
{ name: "Ben", grade: 90 }, { name: "Rod", grade: 90 }, 
{ name: "Rod", grade: 70 }, { name: "Jack", grade: 60 } ]
```

I would like Ben and Jack to be removed since they only have one record in this array. What would be the most elegant way to get this done? I could manually go through it and check, but is there a better way? Like the opposite of

```
arr.uniq! { |person| person[:name] }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr.reject! { |x| arr.count { |y| y[:name] == x[:name] } == 1 }
```

An `O(n)` solution:

```
count_hash = {}
arr.each { |x| count_hash[x[:name]] ||= 0; count_hash[x[:name]] += 1 }
arr.reject! { |x| count_hash[x[:name]] == 1 }
```

Comment: Beautiful, I had gotten the answer somewhat the way you did but in about 6-7 lines. Yours is much prettier.

Comment: @JoshEmory Pretty but O(n^2).  On a long list it may run a long time.  It can be done in O(n).

Comment: Indeed. I assumed his list is small.

Comment: @Gene The list isn't very big. I realize iterating through would take it to O(n) but this is a little more elegant for small lists.

Comment: Very nice answer, Robert.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three more ways that might be of some interest, though I prefer Robert's solution.

Each of the following returns:

```
  #=> [{:name=>"Josh" , :grade=> 90}, {:name=>"Josh" , :grade=>70},
  #    {:name=>"Kevin", :grade=>100}, {:name=>"Kevin", :grade=>95},
  #    {:name=>"Rod"  , :grade=> 90}, {:name=>"Rod"  , :grade=>70}]
```

**#1**

Use the well-worn but dependable [Enumerable#group_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) to aggregate by name, [Hash#values](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-values) to extract the values then reject those that appear but once:

```
arr.group_by { |h| h[:name] }.values.reject { |a| a.size == 1 }.flatten
```

**#2**

Use the class method [Hash#new](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-new) with a default of zero to identify names with multiple entries, then select for those:

```
multiples = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |h,g| g[h[:name]] += 1 }
               .reject { |_,v| v == 1 } #=> {"Josh"=>2, "Kevin"=>2, "Rod"=>2}
arr.select { |h| multiples.key?(h[:name]) }
```

**#3**

Use the form of [Hash#update](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `Hash#merge!`) that takes a block to determine names that appear only once, then reject for those:

```
singles = arr.each_with_object({}) { |h,g|
            g.update({ h[:name] => 1 }) { |_,o,n| o+n } }
             .select { |_,v| v == 1 } #=> {"Ben"=>1, "Jack"=>1}
arr.reject { |h| singles.key?(h[:name]) }
```